# How to get a github account that no one else uses?

Tags: github, reset, account

I have a github account, and I want to get someone else's account which is registered in 2015, and he created two empty repository, and then he was never used the account again.
What can I do to own this account?
I want to get this username.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to use his account, because you want his username?

Comment: @LuVu yes,I want his username.  According to peterevans's answerhint, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this article https://help.github.com/en/articles/github-username-policy

> If you would like to request the account name of someone you believe is violating GitHub’s name squatting policy, please follow the steps in the Changing your GitHub username article before contacting Support. Following these steps will help you determine if the desired account name is available for release and guide you towards contacting Support, where applicable.

I think it will depend if GitHub agree that the username in question violates their squatting policy.